# Bot Service Migration Failing Without an Actionable Error

Tags: azure, bots, botframework, azure-functions, azure-bot-service

I have an Azure Bot Service, AppServiceDomainChecker, that I am trying to migrate to the new Azure Bot Service platform. I click on the "migrate" button on the Bot Framework site and it starts, but it eventually errors out when copying files to the new host. However, there are no messages in the error. It just says "An error occurred:".

I checked my Azure Portal and I see that there is a new Function App created for my bot, but there are no files under the wwwroot folder for the bot. So it seems like there's some issue with copying the files over.

I'm not sure what else I should do. I can create the bot on a Function App and set things up again if needed, but this seems like an issue with the "Migrate" option given.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I have the answer from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-migrate-bot

SDK and Functions bots are not supported for the migration yet.

I also got this internal information:

> The "coming soon" note is in reference to the product previously known as "Azure Bot Service (Preview)", which cannot currently be migrated. If you have an existing "Azure Bot Service (Preview)" bot, then the best method at this time is to create a new "Web App Bot" or "Functions Bot" and move your code over. - from Nils Whitmont ([nilsw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5199616/nilsw)), Bot Framework Engineer

I will proceed with doing that soon.